# Extracting long lines from a file using c++

Tags: c++, string, file

I'm trying to extract data from a large file (A2L file 400 MO) to an ouput file, but the problem that my code don't take lines when they exceeds exceeds a certain length.

> From this part:

```
/begin MEASUREMENT VX106x.mon.te.tfifo.extRamMaxByte "Maximum fill level (for each monitor event cycle) of the external trace memory on the Basemodule"
      ULONG NO_COMPU_METHOD 0 0 0 4294967295
      BYTE_ORDER MSB_LAST
      ECU_ADDRESS 0x91000248
      ECU_ADDRESS_EXTENSION 0xFD
      FORMAT "%.15"
      /begin IF_DATA XCP 
        /begin DAQ_EVENT VARIABLE 
          /begin AVAILABLE_EVENT_LIST /end AVAILABLE_EVENT_LIST 
          /begin DEFAULT_EVENT_LIST 
            EVENT 0x8000 
          /end DEFAULT_EVENT_LIST 
        /end DAQ_EVENT 
      /end IF_DATA 
    /end MEASUREMENT
```

> My code give me this:

```
Measurement:                  VX106x.mon.te.tfifo.extRamMaxByte "Maximum fill level (for each monitor event cycle) of the external trace memory on the Basemodule"
Ecu address found:            0x91000248
Ecu address extention found:  0xFD
Format of measurement found:  "%.15"
```

> But when the line of data is in this form (the line is long):

```
  /begin MEASUREMENT _g_PER_Hil_PerSppRObjHilInputRunnable_PerSppRObjHilInputRunnable_m_radarSensorPropertiesPort_out_local.TChangeableMemPool._._._m_arrayPool._0_._elem._m_collection._m_collection._m_memory._m_values._7_.InputCartesianObject._._m_state._m_vectorCovariancePair._m_muVector._m_data._m_data._m_value._0_ ""
     FLOAT32_IEEE NO_COMPU_METHOD 0 0 -3.40282346639E+38 3.40282346639E+38
     BYTE_ORDER MSB_LAST
     ECU_ADDRESS 0xB0041270
     SYMBOL_LINK "_g_PER_Hil_PerSppRObjHilInputRunnable_PerSppRObjHilInputRunnable_m_radarSensorPropertiesPort_out_local.TChangeableMemPool._._._m_arrayPool._0_._elem._m_collection._m_collection._m_memory._m_values._7_.InputCartesianObject._._m_state._m_vectorCovariancePair._m_muVector._m_data._m_data._m_value._0_" 0
   /end MEASUREMENT
```

> I get nothing in the outuput file.

**Code**

```
int main() {
    string searchedStringtoBegin = "begin MEASUREMENT";
    string searchedStringtoEnd = "end MEASUREMENT";
    string searchedECU_ADDRESS = "ECU_ADDRESS";
    string searchedECU_ADDRESS_EXTENSION = "ECU_ADDRESS_EXTENSION";
    string searchedFORMAT = "FORMAT";

    string outputFile="A2loutputFile.a2l";
    fstream datain, dataout;
    string current_line_in_file;
    string::size_type posbeginMEASUREMENT, posEcuADDRESS, posEcu_Address_Extension, posFORMAT;
    time_t start, end;
    double time_taken;
    string MEASUREMENT_NAME, ECU_ADDRESS, ECU_ADDRESS_EXTENSION, FORMAT;
    cout << "Reading from an A2L file \n";
    time(&start);

    datain.open("examplea2l.a2l",fstream::in);
    dataout.open("A2LoutputFile.a2l",fstream::out);



    while (getline(datain, current_line_in_file,'\n'))
    {
        posbeginMEASUREMENT = current_line_in_file.find(searchedStringtoBegin,0);
        if (posbeginMEASUREMENT != string::npos)
        {
            dataout << "Measurement:                  " << current_line_in_file.erase(0,23) <<endl;
            while (getline(datain, current_line_in_file, '\n'))
            {
                posEcuADDRESS = current_line_in_file.find(searchedECU_ADDRESS,0);
                if (posEcuADDRESS != string::npos)
                {
                    ECU_ADDRESS = current_line_in_file;
                    dataout << "Ecu address found:            " << ECU_ADDRESS.erase(0,18) << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
            while (getline(datain, current_line_in_file, '\n'))
            {
                posEcu_Address_Extension = current_line_in_file.find(searchedECU_ADDRESS_EXTENSION,0);
                if (posEcu_Address_Extension != string::npos)
                {
                    ECU_ADDRESS_EXTENSION = current_line_in_file;
                    dataout << "Ecu address extention found: " << ECU_ADDRESS_EXTENSION.erase(0,27) << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }

            while (getline(datain, current_line_in_file, '\n'))
            {
                posFORMAT = current_line_in_file.find(searchedFORMAT,0);
                if (posFORMAT != string::npos)
                {
                    FORMAT = current_line_in_file;
                    dataout << "Format of measurement found: " << FORMAT.erase(0,12) << "\n" << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // 739369
    datain.close();
    dataout.close();

    time(&end);
    time_taken = end - start;
    cout << "Time of execution: " << fixed << time_taken << setprecision(3) << " seconds" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And when you used your debugger to run your program, what did you see? This is precisely what a debugger is for. If you don't know how to use a debugger this is a good opportunity to learn how to use it to run your program one line at a time, monitor all variables and their values as they change, and analyse your program's logical execution flow. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Looks okay to me (https://ideone.com/hXp7NH) -- perhaps it's related to you not testing whether either the input or output files were successfully opened, but assuming they are.

Comment: On my system, str::max_size() returns about 1G.  Is your string likely to be that large?

Comment: It is weird, because `getline` was invented to handle lines of arbitrary length. Broken implementation could exist, but even using MS VisualStudio I could only reproduce the described behaviour when the input file did not exist in the current directory. So as usual **always control that files could be opened**...

Comment: Thanks for your help. My code stays in the first while loop if it didn't detect the `searchedECU_ADDRESS`, `searchedECU_ADDRESS_EXTENSION` or `searchedFORMAT`

Answer (score 0):

If there's no output, it could be that getline() fails without an exception being thrown (is that possible?), or searchedStringtoBegin is not being found.

At this point:

```
posbeginMEASUREMENT = current_line_in_file.find(searchedStringtoBegin,0);
```

It seems the return value from find() is probably string::npos, and so nothing is output to the dataout filestream.

I hope that helps to answer the question!

Comment: Thanks for your help. My code stays in the first while loop if it didn't detect the `searchedECU_ADDRESS`, `searchedECU_ADDRESS_EXTENSION` or `searchedFORMAT`

Answer (score 0):

```
string outputFile="A2loutputFile.a2l";
dataout.open("A2LoutputFile.a2l",fstream::out);
```

Note that you're not passing `outputFile` name to the fstream (you can use `outputFile.c_str()`). The actual filename you're passing uses an upper case `L` in `A2L`. Maybe you're looking at the wrong file. You should also check `dataout.good()` to confirm the file was actually created.

The second file does not have the extension and format. You may want to add those and try again.

I'm not sure if its a formatting issue on stack overflow but I count 6 spaces before the first word in your first file whereas there are 5 spaces in the second file. Looks like you hardcoded the number of spaces `current_line_in_file.erase(0,23)`. Maybe prefer to seek through the file until you've found what you're looking for.

I would use ifstream and ofstream for the input and output files instead of fstream for both.

I don't think the issues you're seeing are caused by long lines.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My code stays in the first while loop if it didn't detect the `searchedECU_ADDRESS`, `searchedECU_ADDRESS_EXTENSION` or `searchedFORMAT`

Answer (score 0):

**Issue solved ! Thank you all for your help !**

> The problem is not the line length

My code stays in the first `while` loop if it didn't detect the `searchedECU_ADDRESS`, `searchedECU_ADDRESS_EXTENSION` or `searchedFORMAT`

> Solution : Adding a condition to detect the `end MEASUREMENT`

```
while (getline(datain, current_line_in_file,'\n'))
{
    posbeginMEASUREMENT = current_line_in_file.find(searchedStringtoBegin,0);
    if (posbeginMEASUREMENT != string::npos)
    {
        dataout << "Measurement:                  " << current_line_in_file.erase(0,23) <<endl;
        do
        {
            posEcuADDRESS = current_line_in_file.find(searchedECU_ADDRESS,0);
            posendMEASUREMENT = current_line_in_file.find(searchedStringtoEnd,0);
            if (posEcuADDRESS != string::npos)
            {
                ECU_ADDRESS = current_line_in_file;
                dataout << "Ecu address found:            " << ECU_ADDRESS.erase(0,18) << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if (posEcu_Address_Extension != string::npos)
            {
                ECU_ADDRESS_EXTENSION = current_line_in_file;
                dataout << "Ecu address extention found: " << ECU_ADDRESS_EXTENSION.erase(0,27) << endl;
                break;
            }
        } while(getline(datain, current_line_in_file,'\n'));
        
        do
        {
            posEcu_Address_Extension = current_line_in_file.find(searchedECU_ADDRESS_EXTENSION,0);
            posendMEASUREMENT = current_line_in_file.find(searchedStringtoEnd,0);
            if (posEcu_Address_Extension != string::npos)
            {
                ECU_ADDRESS_EXTENSION = current_line_in_file;
                dataout << "Ecu address extention found: " << ECU_ADDRESS_EXTENSION.erase(0,27) << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if (posendMEASUREMENT != string::npos)
            {
                dataout << "\n" ;
                break;
            }
        } while (getline(datain, current_line_in_file, '\n'));

        do
        {
            posFORMAT = current_line_in_file.find(searchedFORMAT,0);
            posendMEASUREMENT = current_line_in_file.find(searchedStringtoEnd,0);
            if (posFORMAT != string::npos)
            {
                FORMAT = current_line_in_file;
                dataout << "Format of measurement found: " << FORMAT.erase(0,12) << "\n" << endl;
                break;
            }
            else if (posendMEASUREMENT != string::npos)
            {
                dataout << "\n" ;
                break;
            }
        } while (getline(datain, current_line_in_file, '\n'));
    }
}
```